How to fix my dynamic routing in React with React Router v5 from /pageName to /my/pageName?
I am in a pickle.
Im using React router v5. On my website I had page link as /pageName. Due to some new features, I changed the links to /:userId/pageName where userId is either "my" or user id. I am struggling to have the old links (/pageName) to redirect to /my/pageName, instead they redirect to /pageName/undefined. Another issue I am facing is that when it is at /pageName/undefined, when I click on pageName2 the url changes to /pageName/pageName2. How do I fix these linking issues? the param :userId should only be "my" for the user's own account or diff user's id.
I need this working in case user tries to just access /pageName like before, instead of /my/pageName. I would not want the linking to break
The below is how I render my Routes
export const routes: RouteItem[] = [
    {
        config: {
            component: RedirectUser,
            exact: true,
            path: '/',
        },
        labelKey: '',
    },
    {
        config: {
            component: pageName1,
            exact: true,
            path: '/:userId/pageName1',
        },
        labelKey: 'pageName1',
        navSection: 'top',
        perm: 'READ',

    },
    {
        config: {
            component: pageName2,
            exact: true,
            path: '/:userId/pageName2',
        },
        labelKey: 'pageName2',
        navSection: 'top',
        perm: 'READ'
    },
    {
        config: {
            component: pageName2,
            exact: true,
            path: '/:userId/pageName2/:item',
        },
        labelKey: 'pageName2',
        perm: 'READ'
    },
]

export const Routes = () => {
const renderRoutes = routes.map((route: RouteItem, index: number) =>
        <Route key={index} exact={route.config.exact} path={route.config.path} component={route.config.component} />);

return(
<Switch>
...
{renderRoutes}
...
</Switch>
)
}



Where do you attempt to navigate/redirect from "/pagename" to "/my/pagename" (or anywhere else for that matter)? How and where is renderRoutes used/rendered? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant routing and navigation code you are working with.

@DrewReese I updated my post. Let me know if it is clear. But this is a preventative measure when users access the old path /pageName. I also take any other ideas and options

my main issue is when I go to /pageName, the url changes to /pageName/undefined or /pageName/pageName. Im not sure how to fix that

I understood the problem, but I was asking where in your code do you redirect users from the old path to the new path? I don't see any "/pagename" route path nor do I see any " /:userId/pageName" route path.

@DrewReese Im not sure If I understand you. My problem is that I CANNOT figure out the redirect, where and how I should do it hence it's not shown. The routes for " /:userId/pageName" is rendered in Routes component which is a child component of my App component.

In case you missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (you earn a badge BTW) there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after someone answers that helps rate and curate content on the site. Cheers.

Having a redirect key in the config and rendering the routes based on that key might solve your problem.
Considering you are using Router v5, here is the implementation:
export const routes = [
  {
    config: {
      path: '/',
      exact: true,
      component: () => <div>Home Page</div>,
    },
  },
  {
    config: {
      path: '/pageName',
      to: '/my/pageName',
      redirect: true,
      exact: true,
    },
  },
  {
    config: {
      path: '/:user/pageName',
      exact: true,
      component: () => <div>Some User Data</div>,
    },
  },
];

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
      {
        routes.map(({ config }, index) => {
          if(config.redirect){
            return (
              <Redirect 
                key={index} 
                from={config.path} 
                to={config.to} 
                exact={config.exact} 
              />
            )
          } 
          
          else return (
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={config.path}
                exact={config.exact}
                component={config.component}
              />
            )
        })
      }
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}


You just need to add a redirect from the old route path "/pagename" to the new route path "/my/pagename" in your router. Ideally you'd just render a <Redirect from="/pageName" to="/my/pageName" /> directly, but you could also integrate it with your current routes configuration.
Example:
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const routes: RouteItem[] = [
  {
    config: {
      component: RedirectUser,
      exact: true,
      path: "/",
    },
    labelKey: "",
  },
  ....,
  {
    config: {
      component: PageName,
      path: "/:userId/pageName",
      ....,
    },
    ....,
  },
  ....,
  {
    // Redirect from exactly "/pagename" to "/my/pagename"
    config: {
      render: () => <Redirect to="/my/pageName" />,
      exact: true,
      path: "/pageName",
    },
    labelKey: "redirectPageName",
    perm: "READ",
  },
];

<Switch>
  {routes.map((route) => (
    <Route key={route.config.path} {...route.config} />
  ))}
</Switch>


Here's a small demo sandbox

This worked! I was trying to automate this where I didn't have to add the redirect for each page, but still struggling to understand the routes.

@mmk Is your question/issue sufficiently addressed/resolved? I can't tell from your comment if you've something still to address/answer/fix/etc.
